# If $A $ and $B$ are independent R.V., will $A^2$ and $B$ be independent?

Tags: random-variables, independence

Given A,B are independent identically distributed random variables

will 
$$E[A^2B]=E[A^2]E[B]$$

(uncorrelation)
$$P_{A^2B}(a,b)=P_{A^2}(a)P_B(b)$$

(independence)

hold?

An initial thought is that one-to-one mapping of random variable will not destroy independence

However the mapping $$f(x)=x^2$$ apparently is not an 1-1 mapping.

Any proof toy example to show if the above two property still holds after mapping?

Comment: Yes if A and B are independent then u(A) and v(B) are independent, for every functions u and v. To get more explanations, you might want to recall how you define the independence of some random variables A and B.

Comment: $P(u(A)\in U,v(B)\in V)=P(A\in u^{-1}(U),B\in v^{-1}(V))=\dots$

Answer (score 1):

Remember that, if $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a Borel-measurable function, then $f(A)$ is a $\sigma(A)$-measurable function. So, in our case, $f(x)=x^2$ is a Borel-measurable function.

Hence, $A^2$ is a $\sigma(A)$-measurable function, and therefore, $\sigma(A^2)\subseteq\sigma(A)$.  Now, using independence of $\sigma$-algebras $\sigma(A)$ and $\sigma(B)$ you can conclude.